# Check for EAP credentials issue

Tags: c++, wifi, wlanapi

I want to check if EAP credentials are present (stored in the registry or not) when connecting to the Enterprise wireless network from the imported profile using my program. I use this method: [WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlansetprofileeapxmluserdata) for storing the user credentials. The imported profile only stores the wireless network xml data and not the username and password. So, what method from Wlan API should I use to verify that the user credentials are present for the specific wireless profile? I only need information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by checking for `wlan_notification_acm_network_available` code, from the MS docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms706902(v=vs.85)):

The `wlan_notification_acm_network_available` notification is sent when all of the following conditions occur:

- The wireless service finds connectable networks after a scan
- The interface is in the disconnected state;
- There is no compatible auto-connect profile that the wireless service can use to connect.

After a while when connecting to EAP profile without the user credentials it gets `wlan_notification_acm_network_available code`. Now the application intercepts it and send a notification to enter the user credentials. The issue is resolved.